# Install Ghostscript v 9.05 (or newer) on CentOS

Tags: centos, ghostscript

I need to use the **ghostscript inkcov device** on my **CentOS** server. The device is said to be available on GS versions **9.05 and newer**. However, `yum install ghostscript` installs version **8.70**.

**What is the easiest way to get the inkcov device to work?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that you can easily download a binary from [the repository](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html), unpack it on the file-system and then just update the PATH variable. After that the application works fine.

Comment: this was easy, can also just make it executable and refer to it with absolute path

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else comes across this:

I found [this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/files/GPL%20Ghostscript/) more helpful. It lists different versions, and then you can download a convenient `*.tar.gz` to unpack / install.

I did `wget` on the URL for the link `ghostscript-9.10.tar.gz`. For some reason it saved to a file called `download`, but it is a `.tar.gz`. So I unpacked with `tar -zxvf download`

`cd` into the new directory, then it's the classic:

`./configure` *note that you can add `--prefix=path` to specifiy the installation directory*

`make`

`make install`

[This link from ghostscript's site](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.14/Install.htm#Install_Unix) was very helpful to me for installation

Comment: *some reason* is because you **are** downloading a file called `download`: have a look at the URL you're `wget`-ing.  You can use the `-O` switch to use a different name: `wget -O ghostscript.tar.gz [URL]`. Also note that building from source will require you to install/build all possible dependencies.

Comment: thanks for the tip on `wget`. Truly, I didn't understand how to have ghostscript *installed* and working from Op's answer, so I posted this. Trying op's, I unpacked it and was left with a single file, `./configure`` did nothing. From there I wasn't sure what to do with that.

Comment: The OP's answer provides links to binary versions of ghostscript. You don't need to compile them, they already are (unless you choose the *Ghostscript 9.15 Source* version). All you have to do is run `gs-915-linux_x86` (or similar).

Answer (score 1):

In CentOS 8 there is an easier way to do this installation:

```
dnf --enablerepo=PowerTools install ghostscript
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with this gist, which worked for me: https://gist.github.com/masbog/a84e9122f9bca6b83e47

```
curl -O http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/ghostscript-9.14.tar.gz &&
tar -xzf  ghostscript-9.14.tar.gz &&
cd ghostscript-9.14 &&
./configure &&
make install &&
make so &&
cp ghostscript-9.14/sobin/libgs.so.9.14 /usr/lib &&
ln -s /usr/lib/libgs.so.9.14 /usr/lib/libgs.so &&
mkdir -p /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ &&
echo "/usr/lib/libgs.so" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libgs.conf &&
ldconfig &&
echo "Installing ghostscript finish" &&
gs
```